# Getting delayed_job to just work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, background, delayed-job

I followed the railscast which uses CollectiveIdea's fork. I'm not able to get it to work. I created a new file in my /lib folder and included this

```
class Device
  def deliver
    #my long running method
  end
  handle_asynchronously :deliver
end

device = Device.new
device.deliver
```

I do a script/delayed_job and that forks an app instance. Now,

1. There's no job activity going on. Nothing in the delayed_jobs table and nothing in the logs. Am I missing something here?
2. How do I set the interval for which the method should be run? (Ex every 30 seconds)

I'm testing this in the development mode (Rails 2.3.2), and soon will be moving this into production.

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Do you see a process for the script/delayed_job that you ran? Do a ps aux | grep delayed_job and see if there is a process running.

AFAIK, you cannot set any time intervals using Delayed Job.

Answer (score 0):

As a first step to diagnose the problem:

1. Stop your job workers
2. Launch a delayed job
3. Check whether it is present in the database.